# How to read text-file using java (android studio)?

Tags: android, android-studio

```
I am very new to android development and I was following Stanford CS193A lectures to learn something. While trying to create dictionary(without using stand-ford library), i feel like I did most of the things right but I am not able to launch app on phone. Here my java code. Please help me.



    package com.hfad.dictionarytwo;

    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.AdapterView;
    import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
    import android.widget.ListView;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Collections;
    import java.util.HashMap;
    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        private HashMap<String, String> dictionary;
        private ArrayList<String> list;
        private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
        private ArrayList<String> fiveDefns;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            dictionary = new HashMap<String,String>();
            list = new ArrayList<String>();
            fiveDefns = new ArrayList<String>();
            readWordsFromFile();

            pickRandomWords();
        }

        private void readWordsFromFile(){
            Scanner scan = new Scanner(getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.grewords));
            //following delimator is for spliting at tab
            while (scan.hasNextLine()){
                String line = scan.nextLine();
                String[] parts = line.split("\t");
                if (parts.length >= 2){
                String word = parts[0];
                String defn = parts[1];
                list.add(word);
                dictionary.put(word,defn);
                }

            }
        }

        private void pickRandomWords() {
            //folowing code shuffles all the words and takes the first three words
            ArrayList<String> threeWords = new ArrayList<String>();
            Collections.shuffle(list);
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                threeWords.add(list.get(i));
            }
            //display the first word, after shuffling ofcourse
            final String theWord = threeWords.get(0);
            TextView theWordView = findViewById(R.id.the_word);
            theWordView.setText(theWord);

            fiveDefns.clear();
            for (String word : threeWords) {
                fiveDefns.add(dictionary.get(word));
            }

            //shuffle it again
            Collections.shuffle(fiveDefns);
            //make adapter to show three definitions on screen
            if (adapter == null) {
                adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,
                        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, fiveDefns);
            } else {
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            }


            ListView listView = findViewById(R.id.word_list);
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);
            listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    //get the posiiton of definition user clicked from threeDefn arraylist
                    String defnClicked = (String) fiveDefns.get(position);
                    //want to know if it is right definition
                    String rightAnswer = dictionary.get(theWord);
                    if (defnClicked.equals(rightAnswer)) {
                        //note that just 'this' will not work b/c we want to refer to over all activity
                        //not this little activity, which is small activity inside overall activity
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "You are awesome", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "You Suck", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                    pickRandomWords();
                }
            });
        }

    }




I have grewords txt file in my res directory .
```

Comment: Can you share a link to the lecture to help others know what's the lecture is about?

Comment: Have you added MainActivity in your manifest file ?

Comment: welcome to stack overflow :) if you have any error logs or any crashes, please add those to your question as well

Comment: also, the format and content of your text file might be useful as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your activity change condition in **readWordsFromFile()** and call **pickRandomWords()** from **readWordsFromFile()**.
See the below code.

Make sure that your file has content like :

```
abcd kolkata valsad
123 auto vapi
789 neha palghar
klj ma ghfgh
mnk fgdgdf papa
```

> **Note:** In your text file data should be in the above format.because you split words using space("\t").

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        private HashMap<String, String> dictionary;
        private ArrayList<String> list;
        private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
        private ArrayList<String> fiveDefns;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            dictionary = new HashMap<String,String>();
            list = new ArrayList<String>();
            fiveDefns = new ArrayList<String>();
            readWordsFromFile();

        }

        private void readWordsFromFile(){
            Scanner scan = new Scanner(getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.grewords));
            //following delimator is for spliting at tab
            while (scan.hasNextLine()){
                String line = scan.nextLine();
                if(line.contains(" ")) {
                    String[] parts = line.split(" ");
                    if (parts.length >= 1) {
                        String word = parts[0];
                        String defn = parts[1];
                        list.add(word);
                        dictionary.put(word, defn);
                    }
                }

            }
            pickRandomWords();
        }

        private void pickRandomWords() {
            //folowing code shuffles all the words and takes the first three words
            ArrayList<String> threeWords = new ArrayList<String>();
            Collections.shuffle(list);
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                threeWords.add(list.get(i));
            }
            //display the first word, after shuffling ofcourse
            final String theWord = threeWords.get(0);
            TextView theWordView = findViewById(R.id.the_word);
            theWordView.setText(theWord);

            fiveDefns.clear();
            for (String word : threeWords) {
                fiveDefns.add(dictionary.get(word));
            }

            //shuffle it again
            Collections.shuffle(fiveDefns);
            //make adapter to show three definitions on screen
            if (adapter == null) {
                adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,
                        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, fiveDefns);
            } else {
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            }


            ListView listView = findViewById(R.id.word_list);
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);
            listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    //get the posiiton of definition user clicked from threeDefn arraylist
                    String defnClicked = (String) fiveDefns.get(position);
                    //want to know if it is right definition
                    String rightAnswer = dictionary.get(theWord);
                    if (defnClicked.equals(rightAnswer)) {
                        //note that just 'this' will not work b/c we want to refer to over all activity
                        //not this little activity, which is small activity inside overall activity
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "You are awesome", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "You Suck", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                    pickRandomWords();
                }
            });
        }

}
```

> ** Note:** you just replace the above code in your file.

Comment: your code works much better than what I had previously. One more doubt, my text file have words format like this: 
abcd - its definition
efgh - definition of efgh

any suggestions on how I would change code slightly to display entire sentences on right side of each word? ofcourse the idea is to display one random word on top and three possible definitions of the word below. seems like textview for definitions right now displays only first word (when I dont use - symbol to separate word and its corresponding defination). Thanks, you helped me a lot